# How to restrict content to Text() on custom view/component using ViewBuilder in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, viewbuilder

I've created a custom component using SwiftUI. It's similar to a dropdown list that resembles a text field but when you tap on it, it will show a sheet containing a list of options. Here's the code for the picker:

```
struct PickerWidget<Content: View>: View{
var action: () -> Void
private let content: () -> Content

init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    self.action = action
}

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.action()
    })
    {
        HStack{
            content()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
    .padding()
}
```

}

And here's how it's being used from the parent view:

```
        PickerWidget(action: { self.isSheetShown.toggle() }){
            Text("US Dollars (USD)")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShown){
            CurrencyPickerView(isSheetShown: self.$isSheetShown)
        }
```

It works perfectly. But I would like to restrict the number of views to just 1 and it has to be ONLY Text(). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to restrict the number of views to just 1 and it has to
>   be ONLY Text(). Is there a way to do this?

Yes, you don't need generics for this purpose, you need to specify Text explicitly and compiler will not allow anything else, and Text is not a container, so always will be just one.

```
struct PickerWidget: View {
   var action: () -> Void
   private let content: () -> Text

  init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Text) {
     ...
```